# Showing that $I(\xi_1,...,\xi_d)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $\xi_1,...,\xi_d \in S^{d-1}$ and $Leb(B)=0$. We define 
$$I(\xi_1,...,\xi_d) = \int_0^\infty \cdots \int_0^\infty 1_B (r_1 \xi_1+\cdots+r_d \xi_d) \prod_{j=1}^d g(\xi_j,r_j) (r_j^2 \wedge 1) dr_1\cdots dr_d $$
where $g(\xi,r) $ is a nonnegative measurable function on $S^{d-1}\times (0,\infty)$.

What I want to check is that $I(\xi_1,...,\xi_d)=0$ if $\xi_1,...,\xi_d$ are linearly independent. How can I derive this by change of variables?

Comment: What is $r_j^2 \wedge 1$?

Comment: Oops! It means minimum.